# Accessing a Javascript namespace from a phtml file

Tags: javascript, php, json, require

I am using a phtml file that needs to read a static json object from a javscript file hosted on the same server.

I am having trouble actually accessing the JSON object so that I can manipulate it and get it to show on the screen (eventually with proper anchors, etc.)

Here is how I am trying to access the object, but php is relatively new to me.

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/my/resource.js';
$json = ns.path.VARIABLE;
?>
<?php echo $json; ?>
```

And my javascript file, located at /path/to/my/resource.js:

```
ns.path.VARIABLE = {
    Part1: {
        'Key1': 'Value1',
        'Key2': 'Value2'
    }
    Part2: {
        'Key1': 'Value1',
        'Key2': 'Value2'
    }
}
```

I am having no success. I can tell that the js file is getting included in the response to the browser, but I cannot get through to the VARIABLE Json object.

Any idea of how to access the JSON, which I will then parse and render to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. PHP runs on the server, while JS runs on the client. Your best chance is to remove the `ns.path.VARIABLE` part from your file, and read it as an actual JSON file by using `file_get_contents()` on it

*Example*

**resource.json**

```
{
    Part1: {
        'Key1': 'Value1',
        'Key2': 'Value2'
    }
    Part2: {
        'Key1': 'Value1',
        'Key2': 'Value2'
    }
}
```

*PHP code*

```
<?php 

$json = json_parse(file_get_contents('resource.json'));
```

Simple as that!

**EDIT**

On the specific code you published, you can do the following, but it doesn't seem safe or flexible:

```
// Load the file as a string
$js_string  = file_get_contents('resource.js');
// Remove the namespace part so that you can parse it as a JSON string
$js_string = str_replace('ns.path.VARIABLE =', '', $js_string);
// Convert it to an associative array you can use in PHP
$array = json_decode($js_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here. First of all, what you call JSON is in fact not JSON at all. Run it trough a tool like http://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see. Proper JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "Part1": {
        "Key1": "Value1",
        "Key2": "Value2"
    },
    "Part2": {
        "Key1": "Value1",
        "Key2": "Value2"
    }
}
```

Also, you are mixing up PHP and Javascript. As others already said, JS runs in the browser, PHP runs on the server. You can't mix them the way you are trying. The answer @Loupax provided is basically correct, but I believe it can be done much easier. And it would not require your included file to be JSON, an ordinary JS object will do. (there is a difference); Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var ns = {
      path: {}
   };
   <?= include '/path/to/my/resource.js'; // this will just paste the contents of that file inside this script block before sending it to the browser ?>;
   // here you can use that object 
   console.log(ns.path.VARIABLE.Part1.Key1); 
</script>
```

Note that I first had to create the `ns` object with a `path` object inside, in order to be able to assign the `VARIABLE` object to it. This also assumes you kept that so called JSON file as is, except for the missing comma between Part1 and Part2

It is hard to tell from just a snippet of your code, but I think you could probably get away with just calling it `variable`, and then you would not have to do that first step. Also a little word of advice, try to be consistent when naming variables. The general consensus is that classes start with an uppercase, function and variables with lowercase, and constants are all uppercase. You do not have to follow those rules, but just try to stick with your choice. It will make coding and  debugging a lot easier.

As a conclusion, my code would probably look something like this:

file/to/include.js

```
{
    part1: {
        key1: 'Value1',
        key2: 'Value2'
    },
    part2: {
        key1: 'Value1',
        key2: 'Value2'
    }
}
```

view.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var paths = <?= include 'file/to/include.js'; ?>;
   console.log(paths.part1.key1); 
</script>
```